# addthis facebook share button can not get og tags

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer, addthis

I have a web page which has a share button from addthis and also necessary og tags as required by facebook share button to pre populate share content.

I have tested the og tags with facebook [debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fsparta-halo-staging.herokuapp.com%2Fdashboard), it all works properly.

However, when I click the share button on the page, it doesn't get all the og tag content.

Do I miss any configuration?

Comment: Can you provide a url to your site so I can help troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Facebook do NOT pick up the og tags immediately. it works automatically the day after